# Liquibase Diff in kubernetes environement

Tags: java, liquibase

I have a problem that didn't even cross my mind for many days ,

which is that I am having a SpringBoot microservice deployed on k8s environment a node that has  pod running it , the microservice will use a* MavenInvoker* to call a plugin that is supposed to do some little operations then i executes **liquibase:diff** and **liquibase:updateSql** for the schema creation , the issue is I have a lot database tables at least 460 table ,the liquibase diff itself takes at least 3mis for it to finish which is a lot , no matter enhancements in terms of Memory issue in my pod , and setting larger Xms Xmx for my maven invoker didn't work either.
What is surprising about this topic is that with the same memory allocation in a code-server pod I can run it through it as a work around , like I would be addressing my project via Code-Server Pod  and the whole maven plugin will take less than a minute to execute.

Further Investigations have been applied I only was able to find out that the cause of the problem the liquibase:diff goal which will take a lot of time computing checksums and writing into Datasouce.xml the changelogs that have been computed .
Any suggestions please ?

I hope that my question doesn't get ignored ,
Best Regards